# How can I copy weights to another mesh which has another rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

Assume I have two identical spheres. I add a rig to the first sphere, then I deform second sphere in sculpt mode without adding new polygons or vertexes. I duplicate the rig and I want to connect this secod rig with my second sphere that the rig could animate this deformed sphere exatly like another rig animates first sphere. Another words I need to transfer weights from the first sphere to the second sphere. But 'weight transfer' option only works with objects that connected to the same rig. So I have two spheres and two rigs.

How can I manage that?

Comment: Unclear. You are talking about a rig and deforming in sculpt mode. How exactly have you rigged your sphere?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy vertex groups (and corresponding weights) from your first sphere to your second one :

- Select second one first
- Then select first one
- Use "Copy Vertex Group to Selected"
  [image]

If deformation bones have same names in both Armature, it will work. 
Else, you need to rename your Vertex groups to fit deformation bone names.